# What is this circle?

Tags: piano, notation

[image]

Can someone tell me what this circle below a measure is?

Comment: You can refer to this wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols#Pedal_marks

Answer (score 20):

The asterisk [image] shows where the [sustain pedal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustain_pedal) should be lifted after an earlier [image] (pedal) marking

Comment: Wait, you can insert images inline with text here?? You learn something new every day...